# When do I have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, privileges

When do I have enough reputation?
I mean isn't there a number after which you are a permanent member that can almost not be removed? Is it the thrusted badge perhaps that you need? Did I overread that? If so I'm sorry.

Comment: You can *always* be removed.

Comment: You can always be but if you are able to reach 20K it will probably be less common 8-).

Comment: ...simply because it is less common to reach 20K, most of all!

Comment: Can we remove this question please?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you mean by "enough".

Comment: When you write *thrusted badge*, do you mean [trusted user](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user)?

Comment: @ Martin Does that imply you wont be removed ? Or removed less easily ?

Comment: @mick I am just asking what you meant in your post, since I have not heard about *thrusted badge* so far. You can read in the link I provided what *trusted user* means; nothing about impossibility of removal is mentioned there.

Comment: @JohnJunior woah. Why? OP is just confused about how SE works. There's nothing wrong about asking!

Comment: @mick reputation has nothing to do with suspension or removal. You're a member since day 1. Reputation is linked to privileges on this site. Anybody can register even unregistered users can ask questions. But the more rep. you earn, the more privileges you get, i.e. the more actions you can take. Among these: ask answers, write answers, write comments, vote up/down, edit other users questions ans answers, vote to close/delete other questions and answers, and many other things. You'll find accurate details in privileges page linked by rob john.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No one is above removal.  The list of your privileges is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Comment: ...although I suspect Mad Scientist and some others might be a bit miffed if they were removed...

Answer (score 7):

Real users are never removed, misbehaviour may result in suspension, but not in deletion of the account. The exception are users requesting self-deletion, sock puppets and blatant spammers.